# Specifying barplot colors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot in ggplot in which I want to color the bars by which range they fall in. I have drawn the hlines to show where I want the color changes: 0.4, 0.5, 0.6. Everything that I could find would color based on a gradient. However, I want every bar that is over 0.6 to be the same green color, every bar below 0.4 to be the same red color, etc.

```
attach(screen2D)
screen2D[order(screen2D[,2]),]
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(screen2D) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(Target, -Median), 
               y = Median),
           stat = "identity",
           fill = "skyblue") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = reorder(Target, 
                                - Median),
                    ymin = Q1, ymax = Q3),
                width = 0.25, colour = "black",
                alpha = 0.9, size = 0.2) +
  ggtitle("Title") +
  xlab("X Label") + 
  ylab("Y Label") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, 
                                   hjust = 1, 
                                   vjust = 0.25)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(0,1)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.40, linetype = "dashed",
             color = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.50, linetype = "dashed",
             color = "red") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.60, linetype = "dashed",
           color = "red")
```

[Plot Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSQoL.png)
The `fill` argument within `geom_bar` requires either length 1 or the same length of the data set, which is 102 in this case. Is there a work around for this?

I thought that `scale_fill_manual` would be useful with the `breaks` argument, but this seems to only specify a separate variable.

```
+ scale_fill_manual(
     values = c("red", "yellow", "orange", "green"),
     breaks = c(Median<0.4, 0.4<Median<0.5,
                0.5<Median<0.6, 0.6<Median))
```

Is there a way to achieve this without having to manually separate the dataset into 4 and add them together individually?

Comment: My advice would be to add a column with the color logic as you describe and pass that column to the `fill` aesthetic.

Comment: @ValeriVoev Thanks for the help. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @ValeriVoev for the comment. The obvious choice of adding the color logic column to the spreadsheet before importing it into R was all I needed.

[Corrected Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuDdT.png)